# Inheriting constructors w / wo their default arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor, default-arguments

C++ Primer (5th edition) on page 629 states:

- If a base class constructor has default arguments, those arguments are not inherited.

I tried this for myself and to me it seems that the derived constructor generated by the compiler also has the same default arguments as the base constructor.

Here's a little test:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    Base() = default;

    Base(int x_, int y_ = 88, int z_ = 99)
        : x(x_), y(y_), z(z_) {}

    virtual void debug() const 
    { std::cout << "\nx - " << x << ", y - " << y << ", z - " << z << '\n'; } 

private:
    int x, y, z;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    using Base::Base;
};

int main() {
    Base B(1);
    B.debug();         // x - 1, y - 88, z - 99
    Derived D(5);
    D.debug();         // x - 5, y - 88, z - 99

    return 0;
}
```

( You can run this here - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26cbb85757c1f021 )

So are we inheriting also the default arguments for a inherited constructor or not?

If not, how come I'm not getting junk for the last 2 members but the same exact values as the default argumuments for the constructor inherited from base?

Also searched on the internet for a clear response about this but found none.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [class.inhctor]:

> The
>   candidate set of inherited constructors from the class X named in the using-declaration consists of actual
>   constructors and notional constructors that result from the transformation of defaulted parameters and
>   ellipsis parameter specifications as follows:
>   — [...]
>   — for each non-template constructor of X that has at least one parameter with a default argument, the set
>   of constructors that results from omitting any ellipsis parameter specification and **successively omitting
>   parameters with a default argument** from the end of the parameter-type-list, and
>   — [...]

We have two non-template constructors of `Base`. The default constructor of `Base` introduces the candidate:

```
Derived() : Base() { }
```

And the other constructor of `Base` introduces one candidate for each successively omitted parameter. Namely:

```
Derived(int x, int y, int z) : Base(x, y, z) { }
Derived(int x, int y)        : Base(x, y) { }
Derived(int x)               : Base(x) { }
```

The default arguments are **not** inherited - we just get a different constructor for each number of arguments. So `Derived(5)` simply calls `Base(5)`, not `Base(5, 88, 99)`.

The end result is the same - just how we get there is a bit different.

Comment: Ok, but why if " Derived(5) simply calls Base(5), not Base(5, 88, 99)." when I print the members of D i get 5, 88, 99?
Shouldn't the last 2 members be left uninitialized?

Comment: @Mugurel Because `Base(5)` calls `Base(int x_, int y_ = 88, int z_ = 99)`. `Derived` doesn't have default arguments, but `Base` still does.

Comment: "The end result is the same - just how we get there is a bit different."
Pffff  :-))))
Thanks!

Comment: Worth noting that the committee is likely going to significantly revamp inheriting constructors via [N4429](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4429.html) (or a revision of that paper), and do so as a DR against C++11.

Answer (score 8):

Your quote from the book is not full.

> If a base-class constructor has default arguments (§6.5.1, p. 236), those arguments
>   are not inherited. Instead, the derived class gets multiple inherited constructors in
>   which each parameter with a default argument is successively omitted. For example, if
>   the base has a constructor with two parameters, the second of which has a default,
>   the derived class will obtain two constructors: one with both parameters (and no
>   default argument) and a second constructor with a single parameter corresponding to
>   the left-most, non-defaulted parameter in the base class

So your Derived class will have 3 inherited constructors with signatures:

```
Derived (int x): Base{x} {}
Derived (int x, int y): Base{x, y} {}
Derived (int x, int y, int z): Base{x, y, z} {}
```

And so you are **not** inheriting any default arguments from base class.

```
Derived D(5);
```

calls the first of above three constructors and base constructor is called like

```
Base(5)
```

> Also note that the default, copy, and move constructors are not
>   inherited. These constructors are synthesized using the normal rules. An inherited
>   constructor is not treated as a user-defined constructor. Therefore, a class that
>   contains only inherited constructors will have a synthesized default constructor.

Comment: This really has no implications regarding my question.

Comment: Great! Didn't look at it this way. Thanks!
 But why if Derived D(5) calls Base(5), when I print the members of D i get 5, 88, 99? Shouldn't the last 2 members be left uninitialized?

Comment: Because Base default arguments didn't go away. They are still there. And Base(5) really calls Base(5, 88, 99)